# How to change the import excel file ID instead of excel file name in google app script?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

the following code run perfectly for me but I would like to change to import excel file by ID instead of excel file name. I am newbie so not sure how to code. Thanks.

Here is my code :

```
function main() {
  importData();

function importData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Clear all content
["order"].forEach(function (s) {
var first = ss.getSheetByName(s);
first.clear();
})
  var xlsxName = "0 - all order - business.xlsx"; //Change source file name accordingly
  var convertID = convert(xlsxName).toString();
  var xLSX = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertID).getSheetByName("order");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ROxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheetByName("order"); //Change output sheet ID
  var lastColumn = xLSX.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = xLSX.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).setValues(xLSX.getDataRange().getValues()); //Sets values from converted xlsx data to output sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(convertID).setTrashed(true); //deletes temporary file
}

function convert(excelFileName) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(excelFileName);
  var excelFile = (files.hasNext()) ? files.next() : null;
  var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
  var config = {
    title: "[Converted File] " + excelFile.getName(), //sets the title of the converted file
    parents: [{ id: excelFile.getParents().next().getId() }],
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
  };
  var spreadsheet = Drive.Files.insert(config, blob);
  return (spreadsheet.id); //Returns the ID of the converted file
}

}
```

I hope to get a modify code that import excel file by ID instead of excel file name in google app script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use the file ID of the XLSX file instead of the filename by modifying your script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var xlsxName = "0 - all order - business.xlsx"; //Change source file name accordingly
var convertID = convert(xlsxName).toString();
```

#### To:

```
var xlsxFileId = "###"; // Please set your XLSX file ID.
var convertID = convert(xlsxFileId);
```

And,

#### From:

```
function convert(excelFileName) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(excelFileName);
  var excelFile = (files.hasNext()) ? files.next() : null;
```

#### To:

```
function convert(excelFileId) {
  var excelFile = DriveApp.getFileById(excelFileId);
```

#### Note:

- When the above modification is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

  ```js
  function main() {
    importData();

    function importData() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Clear all content
      ["order"].forEach(function (s) {
        var first = ss.getSheetByName(s);
        first.clear();
      })

      var xlsxFileId = "###"; // Please set your XLSX file ID.
      var convertID = convert(xlsxFileId);

      var xLSX = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertID).getSheetByName("order");
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ROxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheetByName("order");
      var lastColumn = xLSX.getLastColumn();
      var lastRow = xLSX.getLastRow();
      ss.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).setValues(xLSX.getDataRange().getValues());
      DriveApp.getFileById(convertID).setTrashed(true);
    }

    function convert(excelFileId) {
      var excelFile = DriveApp.getFileById(excelFileId);
      var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
      var config = {
        title: "[Converted File] " + excelFile.getName(),
        parents: [{ id: excelFile.getParents().next().getId() }],
        mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
      };
      var spreadsheet = Drive.Files.insert(config, blob);
      return spreadsheet.id;
    }
  }
  ```